How to Share Specific Documents from a Private S3 Bucket as Attachments in Chat?
I'm working on an application where I upload images and documents to an Amazon S3 bucket that is set to private for security reasons. I need to securely share some specific documents as attachments in a chat feature within my application.
What I Tried
I have configured the S3 bucket to be private to ensure that only authenticated users can access the documents. However, I need a way to share certain documents with users in a chat feature, without making the entire bucket public. I tried generating pre-signed URLs, but I'm not sure if this is the best or most secure approach.
What I Was Expecting
I was expecting to find a secure method to temporarily grant access to specific documents in my private S3 bucket, which can be shared as attachments in the chat. I need these links to be valid only for a limited time to maintain security.
What I Need Help With

Is generating pre-signed URLs the best approach for securely sharing specific documents from a private S3 bucket?
If so, could someone provide a detailed example or best practices for generating and using pre-signed URLs in a Node.js application?
Are there any other methods or best practices for securely sharing specific documents from a private S3 bucket in a chat application?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!


Is generating pre-signed URLs the best approach for securely sharing specific documents from a private S3 bucket?

Yes, this is exactly what S3 pre-signed URLs were designed for.

If so, could someone provide a detailed example or best practices for generating and using pre-signed URLs in a Node.js application?

There are so many examples online, including on this very site, as well as in official AWS documentation, that I'm not going to repeat those here.

Are there any other methods or best practices for securely sharing specific documents from a private S3 bucket in a chat application?

Not really, unless you wanted to proxy everything through your own application instead, but then the implementation would be entirely up to you.
The only thing I would recommend looking into, would be placing CloudFront in front of your S3 bucket and serving the files through CloudFront. Then you could use either signed cookies, or pre-signed CloudFront URLs, depending on which better fits your scenario. Although, if the files you are trying to share are not cacheable by CloudFront, this may not provide any benefit over simply using S3 pre-signed URLs.
